# Setting the innerHTML of an element using a loop and closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to solve a simple exercise with JavaScript closures in order to understand how they work and have come across an error which probably has a simple answer or may not be related to the closure itself.

The html markup i'm using is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ol>
  <li class="track">Test Song</li>
  <li class="track">Test Song</li>
  <li class="track">Test Song</li> 
  <li class="track">Test Song</li>
  <li class="track">Test Song</li>
  <li class="track">Test Song</li>
  <li class="track">Test Song</li>
  <li class="track">Test Song</li>
  <li class="track">Test Song</li>

</ol>
  <p>Now playing track <span id="number"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

and the JavaScript is:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){

  var elNum = document.getElementById('number');
console.log(elNum);
function setUpClick(){

  var elTracks = document.getElementsByClassName('track');


  function clickHandler(){

    return function(track){
      elNum.innerHTML = track;
      };

  }

  for(var i = 0, l = elTracks.length; i < l; i++){
    elTracks[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler(i));

  }


}
setUpClick();
});
```

The output I am getting on click is becoming [object MouseEvent] 
when it should be the actual track clicked. 
I'm not sure what is causing that, here is a fsfiddle:
  https://jsbin.com/gujomef/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Why are you mixing plain JavaScript with jQuery? If you're already using jQuery, it's `.each()` methods with create the closure for you.

Comment: form an answer so you gain the points

Comment: I think you want clickHandler to take an argument

Comment: Why should it be the actual track clicked?

Comment: Answer of what? your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/67/.

Comment: its works now because i fixed it

Comment: im saying if we all want points post that i needed to pass the track to the outer function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the number of the track you clicked on, you could use an `.each()` loop to create the closure for you in jQuery.

```
$(function(){

$('.track').each(function(i, e){
  $(e).click(function(){
    $('#number').text(i);
  });
});

});
```

Comment: If you want to add true innerHTML use `.html()` instead of `.text()`. Just figured there was no need in this case.

Comment: jQuery was neither tagged nor required.